# Need a Regex Expression to get Values Under Column of a table

Tags: regex

Need a regex expression to get values of Neighbor and Up/Down from below table

```
Neighbor V  AS  MsgRcvd MsgSent TblVer  InQ OutQ    Up/Down State/PfxRcd    
87.101.215.1    4   35753   9200    9196    3025    0   0   5d19h   400
172.16.144.113  4   65000   9384    9186    3025    0   0   5d19h   528
```

Expected result is

```
Neighbor  Up/Down

87.101.215.1 5d19h                 

172.16.144.113  5d19h
```

Need to get whatever values under these two columns.

Advance Thanks for the help.

Regards

Riyas

Comment: **Show us what you've tried so far.**  Don't describe it, but edit the question and paste in the actual code.  Then tell us what didn't work.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: @AndyLester : I am trying it via Java script. But its taking too much of time. So thought of trying from Regex expression. I am completely new to this and i have no idea about Regex. That's why asked here.

Comment: See above: **Show us what you've tried so far.**

Answer (score 0):

... I'm still learning Regex, so I'm 110% sure there are better ways, but I came up with this that seems to do the trick:

```
(?<Neighbor>.*?)(?:\s.*?){8}(?<UpDown>.*?)(?:\s.*?)(?:\r\n|\Z)
```

This relies on the fact that `Neighbor` is your first column and `Up/Down` is your 9th.
The logic being:

- Match `Neighbor` as beginning of line up till first space
- Have 8 more spaces with words up till your next captured group
- Match `UpDown`
- Have another space and then a set of characters up till the end of the line or end of string

Remember to set `multi-line`

Hope this helps.